# Delay response for a GET call in nodejs with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, asynchronous

I have two APIs written in Nodejs and Express. Lets call them API1 and API2. API1 queries a DB and gets an ID from this DB. Then API1 performs a GET call to API2 with the ID in it. Then API2 captures this ID and performs its own operations ahead. It is a recursive procedure for each ID. So one GET request for each ID from API1 to API2

But what happens is since I have a lot of IDs, before all of them perform the GET request from API1 to API2, I get a 504 timeout as expected since my API1's GET request does not get any response back.

My question is how can I delay this 504 request timeout that I get in API1 before all my IDs make a request to API2?

Heres the example code from API1:

```
router.get('/getIds', (req, res) => {
    getIDsFromDB();
  });


getIDsFromDB() {
//ids here below is an array of all id's I get from querying my DB
// Example of how ids would look: ids = [{ID:"1234567890"}, {ID:"0987654321"}]
ids.map(Id => {
        let recordId = Id['ID'];
        makePostToAPI2(recordId).then().catch(err => {
            //To check error
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}

makePostToAPI2(recordId){
//I use request-promise npm library to make the request to API2
let url = API2URL + recordId;
    return  rp({
        uri: url,
        method: 'GET',
        json: true
    });
}
```

Comment: If you control both APIs, wouldn't it be more efficient to allow for batch requests in API2? i.e. accept multiple IDs at once, and return an Array of individual results?

Comment: @blex- Should have been like that but API2 has a nested for loop in it. And the data it processes is huge. Thanks for your reply, I'm going to try that out

Comment: In any case, it looks like you can increase the timeout like this: https://www.derpturkey.com/increase-request-timeout-for-express-4/

Comment: Don't use a map. You have no control over the loop. Just use a normal do...while loop and break from the loop if an exception occurs.